# Undefined behavior assignment of 2d array

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

**Update: Answered in comments**

I'm getting some weird behavior when assigning values to my 2d array. When I assign individual values within the 4 x 4 part of the 4 x 9 array, it works fine, but the moment I step into the 5th column and beyond, multiple values are changed instead of just one.

I've modified my copy 2D array malloc several times but the problem persists. I also tried memcpy but that didn't work either.

```
int **data = (int **)malloc(4*sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    data[i] = (int *)malloc(4*4*sizeof(int));
}
// data prints
    9 8 1 4
    2 0 5 4 
    3 0 3 2
    5 9 6 3

// copy of a 4 x 4 2d Array but adding 5 extra columns to it
int **copy = (int **)malloc(4*sizeof(int*));
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    copy[i] = (int *)malloc(4*9*sizeof(int));
    copy[i] = data[i]; // original 2d Array
}
// copy prints
   9 8 1 4 0 0 0 0 0
   2 0 5 4 0 0 0 0 0
   3 0 3 2 0 0 0 0 0
   4 9 6 3 0 0 0 0 0

copy[0][4] = 5;

// copy prints again 
   9 8 1 4 5 0 0 0 0
   2 0 5 4 0 0 0 0 0
   3 0 3 2 0 0 0 0 0
   5 9 6 3 0 0 0 0 0

// [0][4] = 5 good but [3][0] changed from 4 to 5

free(copy);
free(data);
```

I'm expecting that if I assign any values to the 5th-9th column, then only that element should change.

Comment: Did you forgot to copy the array elements? `copy[i]` is just a pointer.

Comment: They are copied.  Columns 1-4 is an exact replica of data.  I just added 5 extra columns to it.

Comment: You're leaking memory. `copy = malloc()` is immediately followed by `copy = something else`... losing the memory

Comment: `free(data);` and then `copy[i] = data[i];`???  You can't dereference `data`  **after** you `free()` it.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE - a short, veryficable and compilable program that reproduces the problem, one including `int main()` and `#include <stdio.h>` and including `#include <stdlib.h>`, at best with a link to ready-to-use source to be compiled in one of the online C compilers. Right now you are assigning pointers and leaking a lot of memory. You are not copying array elements (well, you are copying an array of pointers, to be exact), only copying the pointers to elements of the array, not the elements themselves.